# How to load different data in jstree for different conditions

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have been using jstree to display hierarchical information from the databse. However, I would also want to display the tree for some dummy information if I pass it an empty ajaxUrl. Is there any way to bind different data to the jstree, depending on whether the ajaxUrl is empty or not? 
I tried the following code but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```js
function init_tree(ajaxUrl) { 
  var $ = jQuery;    
  $("#tree").jstree("destroy");    
  $("#tree").jstree({    
    "types": {    
      "category": {    
        "icon": "css/jstree/favicon.png",    
        "valid_children": ["category", "sub_category"]    
      },    
      "sub_category": {    
        "icon": false,    
        "valid_children": []    
      }    
    },    
    "plugins": ["themes", "contextmenu", "types"],    
    'contextmenu': {  
      'items': getContextMenu    
    }    
  }).on('select_node.jstree', function(e, data) {    
    onSelect(data);    
  });

  if(ajaxUrl) {
    $("#tree").jstree({
      'core': {  
        "check_callback": true, 
        "data": {
          "url": ajaxUrl,
          "dataType": "json",
          "success": function(result) {
            $("#language_warning").css("display", "none");  
            if(result.length !== 0) {   
              if(result.error) {             
                console.log("Error: " + result.error);
                $('#tree_data').css('display','none');  
              }  
              else if(!result.li_attr['isfullyTranslated']) { 
                $("#language_warning").css("display", "block");            
              }    
            }   
            else {    
              $('#tree_data').css('display','none');    
              $("#issuer_conf_warning").css("display", "block");    
            }   
          }    
        }    
      }    
    }); 
  }
  else {
    $("#tree").jstree({
      'core': {  
        "check_callback": true,    
        "data": [    
          {'id': 'root', 'text': 'New Visa Purpose'},   
          {'id': 'new_1', 'text': 'New Category', 'parent': 'root'},    
          {'id': 'new_2', 'text': 'New Category', 'parent': 'root'},    
          {'id': 'new_1_1', 'text': 'New Visa Type', 'parent': 'new_1'},    
          {'id': 'new_2_1', 'text': 'New Visa Type', 'parent': 'new_2'}    
        ]
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your code?

Comment: It doesn't work. When I pass a url, it doesn't load any data. When I don't pass any url, it should show the dummy data but it doesnt/

Comment: Your JSON is not in the right format. Check this [bin](http://jsbin.com/pasosum/edit?html,js,output)